# Topic messages disappears from confluent topics after refreshing page

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-topic

Topic messages are disappearing from a topic when using confluent client. The only ones I can see (while not reloading page), are messages which I create using the "Produce" option in the same page. Kafka configurations are ok (I think), but I still don't understand what is wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are producing and consuming messages through a web browser.

Consumers *typically* subscribe to a topic and *commit* the offsets which have been consumed. The subsequent polls do not return the older messages (unless you do a seek operation) but only the newly produced messages.

The term **disappearing** may be applicable in two contexts:

1. As said above, consumer has already consumed that message and doesn't consume it again (because it has polled it already)
2. Your topic retention policy could be deleting older messages. You can check this, by using built in tools like `kafka-console-consumer` or `kafka-avro-console-consumer` with `--from-beginning` flag. If the messages are there means that is an issue with your consumer.

If you are calling `consumer.poll()` on every reload, then you will only get the messages after the previous call to poll (i.e. produced after the last reload). In case, you want all messages that have been present in the topic, since beginning or since sometime, you need to `seek` from `beginning` or since some timestamp or offset. See [seek in KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-long-)